# OpenLdap Replication

Tags: ldap, replication

I have installed openldap on two machines and tried to setup multi-way replication.I am able to perform the multi-way replication (Add/Update/delete) when both the machines are up and ldap is running.

But when my one machine goes down(server2) and records are added,deleted,modified on (server1) are not getting replicated on server2 when its is up and ldap service is running.

**Below are the machine on which ldap is installed:**

```
[root@localhost openldap]# cat /etc/*-release
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

**Openldap version:**

```
[root@localhost openldap]# slapd -V
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.23 (Oct 31 2012 08:14:14) $
        mockbuild@x86-022.build.eng.bos.redhat.com:/builddir/build/BUILD
        /openldap-2.4.23/openldap-2.4.23/build-servers/servers/slapd
```

**Below are the slapd.conf files from both the servers:**

**1. Server1:**

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/duaconf.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/java.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/collective.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/sim-data-attributes.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/eps-pdn-attributes.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/SIMSubscription.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/EPSSubscription.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/PDNSubscriptionContexts.schema
allow bind_v2
pidfile         /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile        /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
modulepath /usr/lib64/openldap
moduleload syncprov.la
serverID 1
database config
access to *
        by dn.exact="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage
        by * none
database monitor
access to *
        by dn.exact="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" read
        by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" read
        by * none

database        bdb
suffix          "dc=example,dc=com"
checkpoint      1024 15
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
rootpw ******redacted******
sizelimit       unlimited
directory       /var/lib/ldap

index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub
overlay syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint 100 10
syncprov-sessionlog 100

syncrepl rid=100
         provider=ldap://172.16.101.60:389
         type=refreshAndPersist
         retry="60 +"
         searchbase="dc=example,dc=com"
         scope=sub
         schemachecking=on
         bindmethod=simple
         binddn="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
         credentials=secret
mirrormode on

loglevel 16777

logfile   /var/log/ldap.log
```

**2. Server2:**

```
[root@localhost openldap]# cat slapd.conf
include         /etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/duaconf.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/java.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/collective.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/sim-data-attributes.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/eps-pdn-attributes.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/SIMSubscription.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/EPSSubscription.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/PDNSubscriptionContexts.schema
allow bind_v2
pidfile         /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile        /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
modulepath /usr/lib64/openldap
moduleload syncprov.la
serverID 1
database config
access to *
        by dn.exact="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage
        by * none

database monitor
access to *
        by dn.exact="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" read
        by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" read
        by * none


database        bdb
suffix          "dc=example,dc=com"
checkpoint      1024 15
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
rootpw *****redacted*****
sizelimit       unlimited
directory       /var/lib/ldap
index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub

overlay syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint 100 10
syncprov-sessionlog 100

syncrepl rid=100
         provider=ldap://172.16.101.36:389
         type=refreshAndPersist
         retry="60 +"
         searchbase="dc=example,dc=com"
         scope=sub
         schemachecking=on
         bindmethod=simple
         binddn="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
         credentials=secret
mirrormode on

loglevel 393

logfile   /var/log/ldap.log
```

**On both the nodes the Syn log are enabled:**

```
# Logging
#  - trace function calls (1)
#  - connection management (8)
#  - ACL processing (128)
#  - stats log connections/operations/results (256)
#  - LDAPSync replication (16384)
#  (1 + 8 + 128 + 256+ 16384)=16777
loglevel 16777
logfile   /var/log/ldap.log
```

**Below are the logs from both the servers**

**Server2:**

```
Apr 30 00:39:29 localhost slapd[5891]: daemon: removing 15
Apr 30 00:39:29 localhost slapd[5891]: conn=1001 fd=15 closed (slapd shutdown)
Apr 30 00:39:29 localhost slapd[5891]: slapd shutdown: waiting for 0 operations/tasks to finish
Apr 30 00:39:29 localhost slapd[5891]: slapd shutdown: initiated
Apr 30 00:39:29 localhost slapd[5891]: ====> bdb_cache_release_all
Apr 30 00:39:29 localhost slapd[5891]: slapd destroy: freeing system resources.
Apr 30 00:39:29 localhost slapd[5891]: syncinfo_free: rid=100
Apr 30 00:39:29 localhost slapd[5891]: connection_get(13): got connid=0
Apr 30 00:39:29 localhost slapd[5891]: daemon: removing 13r
Apr 30 00:39:29 localhost slapd[5891]: slapd stopped.
```

**Server1:Trying to conncet to Server2 but since its stopped so failed**

```
Apr 29 19:10:27 localhost slapd[28124]: =>do_syncrepl rid=100
Apr 29 19:10:27 localhost slapd[28124]: slap_client_connect: URI=ldap://172.16.101.60:389 DN="cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com" ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (-1)
Apr 29 19:10:27 localhost slapd[28124]: do_syncrepl: rid=100 rc -1 retrying
Apr 29 19:10:27 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
Apr 29 19:10:27 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: activity on:
```

**Server1:Adding new entry**

```
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: op tag 0x68, time 1430314931
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: conn=1001 op=15 do_add
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => get_ctrls
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => get_ctrls: oid="2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2" (noncritical)
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: <= get_ctrls: n=1 rc=0 err=""
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: >>> dnPrettyNormal: <IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com>
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: <<< dnPrettyNormal: <IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com>, <IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com>
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: conn=1001 op=15 ADD dn="IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com"
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: oc_check_required entry (IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com), objectClass "SIMSubscription"
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: oc_check_allowed type "IMSI"
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: oc_check_allowed type "objectClass"
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: oc_check_allowed type "structuralObjectClass"
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: slap_queue_csn: queing 0x7fc1c7ffe030 20150429134211.927786Z#000000#001#000000
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: bdb_dn2entry("IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com")
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => bdb_dn2id("IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com")
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: <= bdb_dn2id: get failed: DB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found (-30988)
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => access_allowed: add access to "dc=example,dc=com" "children" requested
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: <= root access granted
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => access_allowed: add access granted by manage(=mwrscxd)
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => access_allowed: add access to "IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com" "entry" requested
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: <= root access granted
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => access_allowed: add access granted by manage(=mwrscxd)
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => bdb_dn2id_add 0x5a: "IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com"
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: <= bdb_dn2id_add 0x5a: 0
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => index_entry_add( 90, "IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com" )
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => key_change(ADD,5a)
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: <= key_change 0
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => key_change(ADD,5a)
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: <= key_change 0
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => key_change(ADD,5a)
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: <= key_change 0
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: <= index_entry_add( 90, "IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com" ) success
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: activity on:
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]:
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: => entry_encode(0x0000005a): IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com
Apr 29 19:12:11 localhost slapd[28124]: <= entry_encode(0x0000005a): IMSI=123,dc=example,dc=com
```

**Server1:After starting the server 2 Server 1 was able to communicate with server2**

```
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: added 14r (active) listener=(nil)
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: conn=1002 fd=14 ACCEPT from IP=172.16.101.60:42695 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: activity on 2 descriptors
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: activity on:
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]:  14r
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]:
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: read active on 14
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: connection_get(14): got connid=1002
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: connection_read(14): checking for input on id=1002
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: op tag 0x60, time 1430314972
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: conn=1002 op=0 do_bind
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: >>> dnPrettyNormal: <cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com>
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: <<< dnPrettyNormal: <cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com>, <cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com>
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: conn=1002 op=0 BIND dn="cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com" method=128
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: do_bind: version=3 dn="cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com" method=128
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: conn=1002 op=0 BIND dn="cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: do_bind: v3 bind: "cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com" to "cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com"
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: send_ldap_result: conn=1002 op=0 p=3
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: send_ldap_response: msgid=1 tag=97 err=0
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: conn=1002 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: activity on 2 descriptors
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: activity on:
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]:  14r
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]:
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: read active on 14
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: connection_get(14): got connid=1002
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: connection_read(14): checking for input on id=1002
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: op tag 0x63, time 1430314972
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: conn=1002 op=1 do_search
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: >>> dnPrettyNormal: <dc=example,dc=com>
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: <<< dnPrettyNormal: <dc=example,dc=com>, <dc=example,dc=com>
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: => get_ctrls
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: => get_ctrls: oid="1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.1" (noncritical)
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: => get_ctrls: oid="2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2" (critical)
Apr 29 19:12:52 localhost slapd[28124]: <= get_ctrls: n=2 rc=0 err=""
```

**Server2:After server 2 was started it was also able to communicate with server1 but the replication did not happened**

```
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: >>> slap_listener(ldap:///)
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: listen=7, new connection on 14
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: added 14r (active) listener=(nil)
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: conn=1000 fd=14 ACCEPT from IP=172.16.101.36:46102 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: activity on 2 descriptors
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: activity on:
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]:  14r
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]:
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: read active on 14
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: connection_get(14): got connid=1000
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: connection_read(14): checking for input on id=1000
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: op tag 0x60, time 1430334810
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: conn=1000 op=0 do_bind
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: >>> dnPrettyNormal: <cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com>
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: <<< dnPrettyNormal: <cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com>, <cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com>
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: conn=1000 op=0 BIND dn="cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com" method=128
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: do_bind: version=3 dn="cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com" method=128
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: conn=1000 op=0 BIND dn="cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: do_bind: v3 bind: "cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com" to "cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com"
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: send_ldap_result: conn=1000 op=0 p=3
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: send_ldap_response: msgid=1 tag=97 err=0
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: conn=1000 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: activity on:
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]:
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: activity on:
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]:  14r
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]:
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: read active on 14
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: connection_get(14): got connid=1000
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: connection_read(14): checking for input on id=1000
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: op tag 0x63, time 1430334810
Apr 30 00:43:30 localhost slapd[6070]: conn=1000 op=1 do_search
```

Comment: I suggest you to enable logging, specifically the `sync` flag. Follow http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconfig.html

Comment: Log are enabled and i have updated it with logs too. Kinldy have alook

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's have a reference for OpenLDAP replication in [this page](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html), section 18.3.3. Your configuration looks more like the one for MirrorMode replication than the one for N-Way multimaster replication.

I think the most likely cause is that you didn't assign a unique`serverID` the the two servers, they both have a value of `1` and the replication overlay can't properly decide who's who.

I can't see any other mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Made the server ID different on both the nodes but still same problem